# Rtti: getting "Invalid class typecast" when calling a method in a class

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I made a small working example of what I'm trying to do, everything works fine but not the part where I want to call a method with Rtti, check the comments in the method DoSomeTask.
I guess looking straight to the line that fails is better than an explanation, but I will try. Briefly, I have some nested classes, the main static class TSCSettings with a public property (Users) which is an instance of the class TUsers. TUsers has a field fAccounting which is an instance of the class TSettingsAccounting. The idea is to load users settings in this way:

TSCSettings.Users.Accounting.LoadSettings(UserID);

and it's working fine like that, but in the method DoSomeTask it fails to call the method LoadSettings of the instance fAccounting with Rtti in the line

**meth.Invoke(vField, [1]); --> exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'.**

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
program Rtti_CallMethods;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  RTTI;

type

  TSettingsAccounting = Class(TObject)
      public
         function LoadSettings(UserID: Integer): Boolean;
  end;

  TUsers = Class(TObject)
      strict private
         fAccounting: TSettingsAccounting;
      public
         constructor Create; virtual;
         property Accounting: TSettingsAccounting read fAccounting write fAccounting;

         function DoSomeTask: Boolean;
  end;

  //Static class
  TSCSettings = Class(TObject)
      strict private
         class var fUsers: TUsers;
      public
         class property Users: TUsers read fUsers write fUsers;
         class constructor Create;

  end;


{ TSettingsAccounting }
function TSettingsAccounting.LoadSettings(UserID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   Writeln('...Task load settings ' + UserID.ToString);
end;


{ TCLUsers }
constructor TUsers.Create;
begin
   fAccounting:= TSettingsAccounting.Create;
end;

function TUsers.DoSomeTask: Boolean;
var
   vCtx: TRttiContext;
   vType: TRttiType;
   vField: TRttiField;
   meth : TRttiMethod;
   sInfo: string;
begin

   //---- fAccounting is already instanciated and calling the method in 
   //this way works fine, but fails when I try to do the same below with Rtti
   fAccounting.LoadSettings(4); 
   //----

   vType := vCtx.GetType(self.ClassType); //--> TCLUsers
   for vField in vType.GetFields do
   begin
      sInfo:= vField.Name; // --> fAccounting

      //------ This way works fine
      meth := vField.FieldType.GetMethod('LoadSettings');
      meth.Invoke(fAccounting, [2]);
      //------

      //------ This way fails: ... exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'.
      meth.Invoke(vField, [1]);
      //------
   end;
end;

class constructor TSCSettings.Create;
begin
   fUsers:=  TUsers.Create;
end;


// -------------------------------
begin
   TSCSettings.Users.Accounting.LoadSettings(3); //This works fine
   TSCSettings.Users.DoSomeTask;
   readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st parameter of `TRttiMethod.Invoke()` is a pointer to the object to call the method on. That pointer can be passed in as either a direct `TObject` pointer, or as a `TValue` containing the `TObject` pointer.

In this case, a `TSettingsAccounting` object is needed. Which is why `meth.Invoke(fAccounting, [2]);` works. But on the failing line, you are giving it a pointer to the `TRttiField` itself, which is why `meth.Invoke(vField, [1]);` fails. `TRttiMethod` derives from `TObject`, so the code *compiles*, but it is the wrong `TObject` to pass in.

You need the `TObject` from reading the *value* of the `TRttiField` (the *value* of the `fAccounting` field), eg:

```pascal
meth.Invoke(vField.GetValue(Self), [1]);
```